# How to Disable Microsoft Edge Guest Browsing on

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, windows-registry, microsoft-edge

I would like to disable Guest Browsing on Windows 10 PC (home edition, so no group policy editor- do have registry edit) on Microsoft Edge (new).
I have found tutorials on how to disable incognito mode (which I have done) and how to disable guest browsing on other browsers but not Edge. How could I do this? I would like to disable all anonymous browsing- potentially applying this across multiple computers- that is provided by guest mode (only users with Microsoft log ins will be able to use the browser).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some commands that will disable InPrivate Mode and Guest Mode on Edge

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge /v BrowserGuestModeEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge /v InPrivateModeAvailability /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

The first command sets the Guest Mode to disabled, while the second command disables Incognito permanently.

While I cannot find a link for Microsoft's documentation regarding these both, I do have one from Google, which is very similar to Edge's as they're both based on Chromium

Docs:

[IncognitoModeAvailability](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=IncognitoModeAvailability)

[BrowserGuestModeEnabled](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#BrowserGuestModeEnabled)

Comment: The documentation you linked to appears to only apply to Google Chrome.  This seems like a classic case of while the registry keys do exist, this content was generated by an AI, which doesn't know the difference between Google Chrome, Chromium, and Microsoft Edge. I could be wrong, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#browserguestmodeenabled) will help you, resolve that disparity.

Comment: I did not use AI to generate this answer, but thanks for the documentation. Tried to find it but Google was of no help.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try this:
Group Policy (Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise only)

1. Use the Windows key + R keyboard shortcut to open the Run command.
2. Type gpedit.msc and click OK to open the Local Group Policy Editor.
3. Browse the following path:
   Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Microsoft Edge
4. On the right side, double-click the Allow InPrivate browsing policy.
5. Select the Disabled option.
6. Click Apply.
7. Click OK.
   Once you've completed the steps, the "New InPrivate window" option will appear grayed out in the Microsoft Edge main menu, and no one will be able to start the experience.

Comment: The OP says he has windows 10 home edition  and he does not have group policy editor. And he also wants to disable guest browsing only, not InProvate or Incognito mode.